# Remember Me problem in ASP.NET MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, remember-me

Greetings. I have a problem with Remember Me possibility. It didn't remember my login. First of all I checked `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie( userName, createPersistentCookie );` in `SignIn` method. The second parameter is `true` if I checkbox is cheked. Also I've checked the cookie named `.ASPXAUTH`
( http://img412.imageshack.us/img412/3585/cookieb.png ).
It expires on a day about. But it's not works. If i try open web application after 10 minutes (for example), I will logged out. 
How can I fix it and how can I enlarge cookie lifetime?

Comment: Can any one help me in this mess?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you're using membership.  Something like...

http://dotnetblogger.com/post/2010/01/11/ASPNET-Membership-Remember-Me-That-Actually-Works.aspx

should work.

Mostly, you need [FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f5z1yty.aspx)